Pads for Flexypins in Eagle CAD?
can anyone give help on creating pads for Flexypins in Eagle?
The hard part is the plated-through oval racetrack slot.  I get the idea that it would be OK to simply drop an SMD rectangle on top and bottom layers, then simply draw a line on the dimension layer.  Does that make sense?
Thanks!

What are flexypins?

Flexypins are a system for socketing boards made with castellated holes (plated half-holes).  The mfr. gives a macro for KiCAD, but no support for Eagle.  The footprint is at: https://github.com/solderparty/flexypin.
